# Can an uncashed check from 1993 still be cashed?

Tags: banking, check

Recently I was going through some old papers and ran across  some paperwork of my mothers, that I had never seen before. Much to my surprise their was a stack of checks that had never been cashed for reimbursement for medical services made out to my mother, dating back to 1993. One was for more than $1000.00. I am the executor of my mother's estate, and I wonder if I have any recourse for perhaps cashing these checks.

Answer (score 1):

If you're in the US, then I don't believe you'll have much luck getting a bank to take the checks.  According to a number of references I've found, this [one](http://www.forbes.com/sites/moneybuilder/2012/04/26/how-long-are-undeposited-checks-good/) being the most recent, checks are good for only 180 days by default, but can be otherwise annotated.  That said, I don't think I've ever seen one annotated for longer than 365 days.

If you really want to pursue this, you might try contacting the party that wrote the checks and ask them to re-issue them.   This works for dividend checks from companies for example.  I've done that when handling an estate myself.